# Hide GridView Column using linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, gridview, rowdatabound

I am trying to hide my gridview columns on RowDataBound event. At the moment, I am doing :

```
e.Row.Cells[4].Visible = false;
```

The problem with this approach is that whenever I change the order of the column in grid veiw, I also have to change the index here.

Also, there is another approach :

```
foreach (TableCell col in e.Row.Cells)
        {
            if (col.Text == "Name")
            {
                col.Visible = false;
            }
        }
```

I was told by someone that it is possible using the LINQ.

Something like:

```
((TableCell)e.Row.Cells.Cast<TableCell>()
             .Where(c => c.Text == "name")).Visible = false;
```

So far, I am unable to do so. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
e.Row.Cells.Cast<TableCell>()
           .Where(c => c.Text == "name")
           .ToList()
           .ForEach(col => col.Visible = false);
```

Comment: Dude, It only hides the Header not the row.. :(

Comment: No I want to hide the Header plus Cell of that Column. This code is only hiding the Header.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else find this. I modified Nikhil's answer to hide the entire column (inluding the Header).

```
e.Row.Cells.Cast<DataControlFieldCell>()
    .Where(c => c.ContainingField.HeaderText == "Name" 
             || c.ContainingField.HeaderText == "Title")
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(c => c.ContainingField.Visible = false);
```